# Excel Interop's set_value method damages values

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I found a problem while using the set_value method. I wrote the simplest possible code to exclude my mistakes.

When I read some cells and then write them back to sheet using set_value while:

- any filters are active in xlsx file,
- 2 or more columns are get/set,

some of the cells are corrupted (they are empty or contain junk like #N/D!). When I disable filtering in worksheet or in program before using set_value, everything works fine. I can't find any info about this specific problem in google, am I doing something really stupid?

```
Excel.Workbooks workbooks;
Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
Excel.Application excelApplication;
excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
excelApplication.Visible = false;
workbooks = excelApplication.Workbooks;
workbook = workbooks.OpenXML(file);
sheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

Excel.Range excelRangeR = sheet.UsedRange;
object[,] valueArrayR = (object[,])excelRangeR.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
//if uncomment line     below (or manualy disable filters in XLSX file), set_value works fine
//sheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
excelRangeR.set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, valueArrayR);

workbook.Save();
workbook.Close();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelRangeR);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
excelApplication.Quit();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the filters on, but if there is an *active filter* on the sheet, that has to be removed before setting the value of the cells. I think what is happening is that when you set the object[,] variable, it's populating the array with all the data in the range, including the rows that are not visible, but when you set the value of the range to the object[,] array, it only overwrites the visible rows. It's either that or vice versa.

Sorry if this code is incorrect. I'm just guessing at the C# Interop syntax. I don't use it all that often.

```
if (sheet.get_FilterMode()) {
    sheet.ShowAllData();
}
```

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to save the current value of the worksheet filters, so it would be difficult if you need to be able to restore the filters after the paste operation.

Comment: I tried to read->write->read test range and it seems that get_values reads all the data properly, set_values makes a random mess after first filtered-hidden row.
I was hoping that I made a mistake and there is some method to write values with active filters, but it seems that I have to use your code:)

Comment: Yeah, I had run into this issue before. The only solutions i found are to clear the filter or paste the data one row at a time, which is very slow for a lot of data.